# How to convert entitybase type to entity type in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, type-conversion

I tried code below in .NET 3.5 but got exception at line shown in comment:

`Cannot convert type 'TUnpaid' to 'ClassLibrary1.Unpaid'`

How to fix this in .NET 3.5 ?

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class EntityBase
    {
        public virtual void Save<T>(T dok) where T : EntityBase, new()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Unpaid : EntityBase
    {
        public override void Save<TUnpaid>(TUnpaid dok)
        {
            // Cannot convert type 'TUnpaid' to 'ClassLibrary1.Unpaid'  
            var kup = (Unpaid)dok;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either should write an [operator of type conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx), or write a method (or class) which establishes the [connections between two types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx).

In your code sample you use the two different types (`TUnpaid` and `Unpaid`) with no connection between them.

Answer (score 4):

If you make your EntityBase class generic, I think you can solve this problem:

```
public class EntityBase<T>
{
    public virtual void Save<T>(T dok) where T : EntityBase<T>, new()
    {
    }
}

public class Unpaid : EntityBase<Unpaid>
{
    public override void Save<Unpaid>(Unpaid dok)
    {
        // dok is now of type Unpaid and doesn't need the cast
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I refactored code and moved Save method to entity method so generic type passing is not needed. Inside entity method this can used, type parameter is not required